# Using Func<> on arrays affects the input and more

Tags: c#, lambda

Here is my Main:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<float, float, float> multiply = (x, y) => x * y;

    float[] array1 = new float[] { 2 };
    float[] array2 = new float[] { 2 };

    float[] test = array1;

    float[] newArray = UseFunc(array1, array2, multiply);

    Console.WriteLine(newArray[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(array1[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(test[0]);
}
```

UseFunc definition:

```cs
public static float[] UseFunc(float[] input, float[] input2, Func<float, float, float> func)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        input[i] = func(input[i], input2[i]);
    }
    return input;
}
```

The problem is that both `array1` and `test` are also getting affected by the function and the output is:

```
4
4
4
```

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Arrays are reference types, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) You need to create a copy of your array: `float[] test = array1.ToArray();`

Comment: 'float[]' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray'. Any other way to copy an array?

Comment: You'll need to use the namespace `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are references so you need to create a local copy inside of the function. So this is how your function will look:

```
public static float[] UseFunc(float[] input, float[] input2, Func<float, float, float> func)
{
    float[] temp = (float[]) input.Clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = func(input[i], input2[i]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```